# Div spacing with window resizing

Tags: html, css

I would need advice on how to make those text boxes (div) when I shrink the page so that they do not plot so that they are relative to the page and adjust themselves to the page size.
I drag and drop text into those textboxes (it's like one module on my page) and I need it so that the boxes don't overlap like this when the screen is smaller.

My css code:

```
#textBox1 {
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #535353;
}

#textBox2{
    float: right;
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-inline: 745px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    border: 1px solid #535353;
}

#textBox3{
    float: right;
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-inline: 405px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    border: 1px solid #535353;
}

#textBox4{
    float: right;
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-inline: 75px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    border: 1px solid #535353;
}
////////////////////////
//Bottom line
#textBox5{
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #535353;
}

#textBox6{
    float: right;
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-inline: 745px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    border: 1px solid #535353;
}

#textBox7{
    float: right;
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-inline: 405px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    border: 1px solid #535353;
}

#textBox8{
    float: right;
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 70px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-inline: 75px;
    margin-top: -70px;
    border: 1px solid #535353;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div id="technology-box">
    <div id="textBox1" class="react-to-dark" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="autprumysl"></div>
    <div id="textBox2" class="react-to-dark" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="zdravotnictvi"></div>
    <div id="textBox3" class="react-to-dark" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="doprava"></div>
    <div id="textBox4" class="react-to-dark" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="finance"></div>
    <br>
    <div id="textBox5" class="react-to-dark" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="autprumysl_text"></div>
    <div id="textBox6" class="react-to-dark" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="zdravotnictvi_text"></div>
    <div id="textBox7" class="react-to-dark" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="doprava_text"></div>
    <div id="textBox8" class="react-to-dark" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-id="finance_text"></div>
  </div>
```

Example of a problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), it's very easy.